# What's the cost and performance implications for BigQuery Native JSON data type?

Tags: json, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I am planning to use the [Native JSON data type](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types#json_type) in [BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/). Before that, I am planning to understand the implications of JSON data types and best practices for JSON data type.

For example, the BigQuery is a columnar data store, so if I store a large JSON say 5 MB (in total of 100 properties) for each row and if my table contains 10 million rows for a single partition what are the side effects in terms of cost and performance if I use some specific JSON field (say key1.key2, key2.key2) in a select clause or as an aggregated field? I tried the documentation and I don't find any drawbacks or limitations. Does that mean is it safe to use for any use cases without impacting much on performance and Analysis cost?

Answer (score 1):

With BigQuery, if you use on-demand pricing, you pay for what you read.

In addition, as you mentioned, BigQuery use a columnar storage mode. Therefore, if a column use the JSON type, the whole column is read.

If you get only a property in the JSON, that change nothing. BigQuery need to read the whole column, then to apply the JSON path filter and get your value(s).

In term of performance, you can deduce that the whole JSON need to be read and process (to get the value). So, larger is your JSON and/or higher is the number of row -> longer is the processing time.

Comment: Thanks Guillamue. That was my guess as well, thought to find it in official documentation to be 100% sure.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: BigQuery scans only the necessary parts of the native JSON column.

I just had the same question, and I asked Google Bard, this is the answer by Bard:
**BigQuery intelligently scans only the necessary parts of the JSON column when you query specific fields. It doesn't automatically scan the entire column.**

To verify if that is indeed the case, I found this blog post: https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/databases/how-bigquery-powers-semi-structured-data-storage

A few key takeaways from the blog post:

- On ingestion, JSON data is shredded into virtual columns to the extent possible.
- At ingestion time, after shredding the JSON data into virtual columns, the logical size of each virtual column is calculated based on the data size for specific types such as INT64, STRING, BOOL.
- When the query is run, customers are only charged based on the size of the virtual columns that were scanned to return the JSON paths requested in the SQL query.